# Can i dereference an lxml.etree.AncestorsIterator?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using lxml to manipulate a dbschema expressed in an xml file.  It looks something like this:

```
<Tables>
<Table name = "table1">
<Columns>
<Column name="COL1">...</Column>
<Column name="COL2">...
    <References>
    <Reference>TABLENAME</Reference>
    </References>
</Column>
</Table>
...
</Tables>
```

Currently I want to look at the references, and get the table and column names for those references.  The following works:

```
refiter = mytree.iter("Reference")
for r in refiter:
   nameiter =r.iterancestors("Table")
   for n in nameiter:
       tablename = .get("name")
```

I don't like this solution, because I know that my nameiter can only iterate over a single element -- it only has one parent "Table".  It seems that in python I can only use an iterator in a loop.  But I find it a bit silly.  I know I have only one ancestor "Table".  Can I dereference the iterator directly somehow?  Or is there an alternative method to getting this information that's more suitable?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you want,  what does *Can I dereference the iterator directly somehow?* mean? `"//Reference/ancestor::Table/@name | //Reference/ancestor::Column/@name")` would get both the table and column names in a single query

Comment: My mother-tongue is C++, so when I"m missing the vocabulary in another language I tend to use the C++ words, and hope that they map in a comprehensible way.  In C++ if I got an iterator to the first element, I could just 'derefrence' -- get access to the object the iterator points to directly.    So I could just skip the loop-over-one loop.  I tried your query, but I'm afraid its correct usage was beyond me.  I wound up getting a list of all table and column names... not what i want.

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the need for `for n in nameiter` ans just get the previous Table and Column name? Maybe some valid input and expected output would make it a little more clear.

Comment: I think it was a poor choice on my part to use the word dereference, althoughI think a C++ programmer would understand what I'm trying to do.    Basically I have a child element.  That child element has a single ancestor "Table", whose "name" attribute I want to get.  Can I get that without the loop-over-one-element?

Comment: @Spacemouse, there are numerous options, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an xpath to get both the ancestors you want

```
x = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tables>
<Table name = "table1">
<Columns>
<Column name="COL1">...</Column>
<Column name="COL2">...
    <References>
    <Reference>TABLENAME</Reference>
    </References>
</Column>
</Columns>
</Table>
<Table name = "table2">
<Columns>
<Column name="COL2">...</Column>
<Column name="COL3">...
    <References>
    <Reference>TABLENAME</Reference>
    </References>
</Column>
</Columns>
</Table>
</Tables>"""


import lxml.etree  as et

xml = et.fromstring(x)

refs = xml.iter("Reference")
print([(ref.xpath("./ancestor::Table/@name")[0], ref.xpath("./ancestor::Column/@name")[0]) for ref in refs])
```

Which would give you:

```
[('table1', 'COL2'), ('table2', 'COL3')]
```

Or if the Column is always the grandparent:

```
 [(ref.xpath("./ancestor::Table/@name")[0], ref.xpath("./../../@name")[0]) for ref in refs]
```

using your own logic, you can just call next on iterancetors:

```
refs = xml.iter("Reference")


for r in refs:
   print(next(r.iterancestors("Table")).get("name"))
   print(next(r.iterancestors("Column")).get("name"))
```

Which would give you:

```
table1
COL2
table2
COL3
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are interested in only the first result of the iterator, you can use the `next` method to get the first element, and avoid the unclear/unnecessary `for` loop.

```
xml_string = """
<Tables>
<Table name = "table1">
<Columns>
<Column name="COL1">...</Column>
<Column name="COL2">...
    <References>
    <Reference>TABLENAME</Reference>
    </References>
</Column>
</Columns>
</Table>
<Table name = "table2">
<Columns>
<Column name="COL2">...</Column>
<Column name="COL3">...
    <References>
    <Reference>TABLENAME</Reference>
    </References>
</Column>
</Columns>
</Table>
</Tables>"""


import lxml.etree as ETree

root = ETree.fromstring(bytes(xml_string, 'UTF-8'))

refiter = root.iter('Reference')
for r in refiter:
    nameiter = r.iterancestors('Table')
    name = next(nameiter).get('name')
    print(name)
```

If you wanted to access results by index, you can generate a list from the iterator first.

```
tables = list(r.iterancestors('Table'))
print(tables[0].get('name'))
```